# Decoupling noises

Tags: variance, covariance, noise

This is an experimental physics problem:

Say I have 3 random variables $P_1, P_2, P_3 $ such as :

$\Delta P_i=\Delta_Q P_i +\Delta_0P_i \ \ \forall i$, where $\Delta$ is the variance, this equations means that the variance  of  $P_i$ is the sum of two variances (experimental noises are independent and added quadratically).

These noises are different in nature, they are due to two different physical effects, the first one indexed $Q$ correlates the three variables in the sense that :

${\rm cov_Q}(P_i,P_j)=\overline{P_i}\times\overline{P_j}$, where the bar denotes the average. Here ${\rm cov_Q}(P_i,P_j)$ is the covariance of the two variables would have, if they were only affected by the physical effect Q (I hope it makes sense).

The other one does not correlate the three variables :
${\rm cov_0}(P_i,P_j)=0$

**Question:** Is it possible to extract the value of $\Delta_Q P_i$ or equivalently $\Delta_0 P_i$ knowing that I have experimental access to **all** $\overline{P_i}$ and $\Delta P_i$ (and any other variance or average of observables I can construct with the $P_i'$ such as $P_i+P_j$...) ?

Thank you all